# How to popup a record in OPEN EPIC CRM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, crm

I have a patient record in open epic CRM, how to search the patient record and popup the record to screen via API or any other technology.

Answer (score 1):

How far have you gotten? If you're trying to use the SMART on FHIR resources, you'd need to perform a patient search as specified in the [HL7 Specs](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html). From there, the response is a JSON object as specified in the HL7 schema.

Fundamentally, it's just like calling any other RESTful web service except that the schema is an industry standard. If you post code & the specific issues you're having that would help.